# How to save an image from screen to new database record

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a record stored in SQL with an image file stored as one of the columns of data.

On a form that is used to make a "close copy" of the record (change contents of one or two fields, but leave the rest the same) I am displaying the image for the user to see.

How can I save the contents of this image control into the new database record?
Right now the save works, except that I am having to save an int value of 0 in place of the image file contents.

Save query:

```
protected void ButtonUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string vAuthor = (CloneRecord.FindControl("txt_author") as TextBox).Text;
        string vDate = (CloneRecord.FindControl("txtDate") as TextBox).Text;
        string vStem = (CloneRecord.FindControl("txt_stem") as TextBox).Text;
        string vRespA = (CloneRecord.FindControl("txt_RespA") as TextBox).Text;
        string vRespB = (CloneRecord.FindControl("txt_RespB") as TextBox).Text;
        string vRespC = (CloneRecord.FindControl("txt_RespC") as TextBox).Text;
        string vRespD = (CloneRecord.FindControl("txt_RespD") as TextBox).Text;
        string vRespE = (CloneRecord.FindControl("txt_RespE") as TextBox).Text;
        string vAnswer = (CloneRecord.FindControl("txt_Answer") as DropDownList).SelectedValue;
        string vCritique = (CloneRecord.FindControl("txt_Critique") as TextBox).Text;
        string vKeyLO = (CloneRecord.FindControl("txt_KeyObjective") as TextBox).Text;
        string vReference = (CloneRecord.FindControl("txt_References") as TextBox).Text;
        int vPractice1 = Convert.ToInt32((CloneRecord.FindControl("DDPractice1") as DropDownList).SelectedValue);
        int vPractice2 = Convert.ToInt32((CloneRecord.FindControl("DDPractice2") as DropDownList).SelectedValue);
        int vPractice3 = Convert.ToInt32((CloneRecord.FindControl("DDPractice3") as DropDownList).SelectedValue);
        int vPractice4 = Convert.ToInt32((CloneRecord.FindControl("DDPractice4") as DropDownList).SelectedValue);
        string vImage1 = (CloneRecord.FindControl("Image1Content") as TextBox).Text;
        string vImage2 = (CloneRecord.FindControl("Image2Content") as TextBox).Text;
        string vImage3 = (CloneRecord.FindControl("Image3Content") as TextBox).Text;
        string vImage4 = (CloneRecord.FindControl("Image4Content") as TextBox).Text;
        string vIName1 = (CloneRecord.FindControl("Image1Name") as TextBox).Text;
        string vIName2 = (CloneRecord.FindControl("Image2Name") as TextBox).Text;
        string vIName3 = (CloneRecord.FindControl("Image3Name") as TextBox).Text;
        string vIName4 = (CloneRecord.FindControl("Image4Name") as TextBox).Text;
        string vQuestionID = (CloneRecord.FindControl("IsCloneOf") as TextBox).Text;
        int vImageFile1 = 0;
        int vImageFile2 = 0;
        int vImageFile3 = 0;
        int vImageFile4 = 0;

        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS1"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                string query = "insert into Questions values (@Author, @ImageFile, @Image1Content, @Image1Name, @ImageFile2, @Image2Content, @Image2Name, @ImageFile3, @Image3Content, @Image3Name, @ImageFile4, @Image4Content, @Image4Name,@SubmitDate, @Stem, @RespA, @RespB, @RespC, @RespD, @RespE, @Answer, @Critique, @KeyObjective, @Reference, @PracticeArea1, @PracticeArea2, @PracticeArea3, @PracticeArea4, @IsCloneOf)";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store is as a [BLOB (Binary Large Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895234.aspx) which is intended to store unstructured data, such as images and documents.

Comment: The question is more how do I grab the image off the web page being viewed now, and store the image into the new SQL record being created by this query. I have the table structure already that is saving the image. Image is originally uploaded when the "parent" record is created.